# why I am unable to use global objects

Tags: node.js, express, global

I have a `config` file:

```
     const _ = require('lodash');        
     const config = require('./config.json'); 
     const defaultConfig = config.development;
     const environment = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
     const environmentConfig = config[environment]; 
     const finalConfig = _.merge(defaultConfig,environmentConfig);
     global.gConfig = finalConfig; 
     global.lodash = _;
```

**Server file:**

```
const express = require('express');
// environment variables
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';

const config = require('./config/config.js');

// module variables
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json(global.lodash.compact([null,1,2,null,"",3]));
});

app.listen(global.gConfig.node_port, () => {
});
```

When I am trying to access the globals in my server file, I have required the `config.js`. Without that, It shows an error. Then how can we say It a global variable? Is there any other way? 
I am using `Node 8.x`

Comment: I don't know why it isn't working, but it's a bad design.  Just export the config from your config.js file and then `require()` it in anywhere you need it.  That's the recommended architecture for node.js for a bunch of reasons.  Since modules are cached, the 2nd time you `require()` the same module, no actual code runs - it just  returns to you the previously loaded module.  It's safe and efficient and doesn't have the problems that using globals have.

Comment: `require('./config/config.js')` will load `config.js`, thereby executing the assignments you’re doing in that file. Without that, nothing gets assigned to `global` and the values will be `undefined`. I recommend avoiding using globals - [see my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58817146/199263)

Comment: @AndreasPizsa - Do you not see that the server file already has `const config = require('./config/config.js');`?  They are already loading it.

Comment: @jfriend00 OP wrote "_I have required the config.js. **Without that, It shows an error**. Then how can we say It a global variable?_". It seems like the OP wants to better understand how globals and `require` work.

Comment: @AndreasPizsa - Hmmm, OK that's not how I understood the question, but I guess that could be what they mean.  Kind of an unclear question, IMO.  I thought they were saying the code they show as written did not work.

Comment: @jfriend00 Basically I want to make `config` & `lodash` global. I want to make it global in one file and then use globals without requiring it in any other file. Kindly help. @AndreasPizsa

Comment: And what's wrong with the code you already have?

Comment: Problem is, When I have already made `config` global, then why it is required to write `const config = require('./config/config.js');`. I am unable to understand that.

Comment: It's only required to have SOME code somewhere in your project load config.js.  All that is required is this: `require('./config/config.js');`. If that code doesn't exist anywhere, then config.js is never loaded by node.js and never gets to initialize the globals you want to use.  FYI, I'm with the rest of the chorus here in that using globals in this way is a bad design decision in node.js and is considered an anti-pattern as it ruins the clean modularity and code reuse paradigm in node.js where each module loads in what it needs independently.

Answer (score 1):

The `require` function does a lot of things. For starters, it returns the `module.exports` from the required module.

But it also **executes all the code in the required module**, as if the whole module were a function.

So, you need to actually `require` your `config` file somewhere in order for the following lines:

```
 global.gConfig = finalConfig; 
 global.lodash = _;
```

to be executed. If you don't require `config` at least once, your program will never set `lodash` or `gConfig` in the `global` object.

Now, however, once you do this, you can use `global.lodash` later in any file, even if that file does not `require` the `config` file.

So, basically, any other file required from `server` after you require `config` will have real global access to `global.lodash` without any need to require `config` itself.

---

Now, however, even if this answer does really answer your question, I would consider @AndreasPizsa answer thoroughly, since it is true that having a program with a lot of global variables usually are difficult to reason about.

In your case, why do you setup `lodash` as `global.lodash`? Any module in your program could just do  `const lodash = require('lodash')` by itself.

It is also worth to mention that `require` does cache the required modules. The second time you require a module, the require call won't execute the code again, it will return the cached module, so using `require` from several files to retrieve the same module (as if were in `global`) is pretty much safe.

Comment: Where Should I require my config file to access 
```global.gConfig = finalConfig; 
 global.lodash = _;```? In `server.js`?

Comment: at the start of the program, so you load `global` with stuff and then any of your modules, regardless from where they are required, can have access to the stuff you're putting into `global`.

Answer (score 0):

The `require('./config/config.js')` in your server file loads config.js, thereby executing the assignments you’re doing in that file. Without that, nothing gets assigned to `global` and the values will be `undefined`.

### Larger Context

This may not be the answer you’re directly looking for, but I think it’s the answer you need to hear, because there’s a bigger problem hiding behind the globals.

The actual challenge here is to *avoid global variables* and to handle configuration in a way that’s safe to use in production.

These two pointers will be helpful at that:

- [12factor: Store config in the environment](https://12factor.net/config)
- [dotenv-safe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-safe)

#### Store config in the environment

> Apps sometimes store config as constants in the code. This is a violation of twelve-factor, which requires strict separation of config from code. Config varies substantially across deploys, code does not.
>
> A litmus test for whether an app has all config correctly factored out of the code is whether the codebase could be made open source at any moment, without compromising any credentials.

#### dotenv-safe

> `dotenv-safe` is a zero-dependency module that loads environment variables from a .env file into process.env. Storing configuration in the environment separate from code is based on The Twelve-Factor App methodology.

I hope this helps!